# wrong echo appearing after selecting from drop down menu

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a basic mysqli code below where it performs a query to select CourseId and Course Name from database and display it in a drop down menu.

```
$sql = "SELECT CourseId, CourseName FROM Course ORDER BY CourseId"; 

    $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

    $sqlstmt->execute(); 

    $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbCourseId, $dbCourseName);

    $courses = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data 

    $courseHTML = "";  
    $courseHTML .= '<select name="courses" id="coursesDrop" onchange="getModules();">'.PHP_EOL; 
    $courseHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

    while($sqlstmt->fetch()) 
    { 
    $course = $dbCourseId;
    $coursename = $dbCourseName; 
    $courseHTML .= "<option value='".$course."'>" . $course . " - " . $coursename . "</option>".PHP_EOL;  

    $outputcourse = ""; 
    $outputcourse .= "<p><strong>Course:</strong> " . $course .  " - "  . $coursename . "</p>";

    } 

    $courseHTML .= '</select>';
```

Now lets say the drop down menu contains these courses below:

```
INFO101 - Information Communication Technology
INFO102 - Computing
```

For some strange reason no matter which course I choose, it always echos the CourseId and CourseName `INFO102 - Computing` underneath the drop down menu. Why is this?

Comment: if the problem happens when you CHOOSE a course from the drop down menu maybe the problem is from javascript?

Comment: @Naryl, please look at comment I sent to Abu below. The problem is when I select the option and them SUbmit. The problem isn't in the drop down menu. it is echoing what I have selected underneatch which is this code: `$outputcourse = ""; 
    $outputcourse .= "<p><strong>Course:</strong> " . $course .  " - "  . $coursename . "</p>";
`

Comment: it would help to see the code for getModules() function then. I mean, you have a problem when doing a submit using what you generate with the PHP above, but we have no code of the submit part.. so I can't really check what's wrong :S

Comment: @Nayal I updated code to include code on course drop down menu, module drop down menu, the outputs of the course id and name and module id and name and getModules() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<p><strong>Course:</strong>.....</p>` This may be causing the problem,

because I don't think its valid to have tags other than `<option></option>` inside a `<select></select>` tag.

Try removing those stuff and see if the output appears in drop down.

Comment: I moved the "outputcourse" variable outside the select but still no luck. Problem is no matter which course I choose from drop down, it keeps stating that Course `INFO102...` is chosen in the echo UNDERNEATH the drop down menu. Here is a live demo [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/editsessionadmin.php). In the drop down menus select Course `INFO101...` in Course Drop Down menu and select any module in `Module` drop down menu. Submit page and underneath you see the Course it states I selected is incorrect